# How to call base class constructor alone through derived class object in c#?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I got the following question during an interview: "how can you call base class constructor (default constructor) alone from derived class object". That object should not call derived class default constructor. How is it possible?

This is the code:

```
class a
{
    public a()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Base class called");
    }    
}
class b : a 
{
    public b()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Derived class");
    }
}
```

I just want to display base class constructor without the one from derived class being invoked. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this yourself?

Comment: don't make derived class constructor... it will automatically first call base class.

Comment: What did  you answer? It´s not *our* interview, is it?

Comment: I did not answer for this question. because once you create object for derived class it will call both base and derived class.

Comment: There you have your answer.

Comment: You can use `Reflection` and `static methods` to achieve this behavior. Create static method in b (which will ivoke only *static* constructor) and use reflection inside of it, or instantiate `a` directly via `new a()`

Comment: @chinnathambir pls check the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The way the question is worded sounds like a riddle, but I'd assume it means 'how do you call the base class default constructor from a derived class's non-default constructor'.

This will implicitly happen anyway, but if you want to be explicit you're looking for the [`base` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) to specify which constructor to call in the base class:

```
public Derived(object param) : base()
{

}
```

The only way to not call the derived class's default constructor is to have a non-default constructor in the derived class and instantiate the object using that.

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jzPbTt) for a demo containing both default and non-default constructors.

Comment: Both class contain message box.

Comment: @chinnathambir is that relevant?

Comment: I too dont know, but the interviewer asked like this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following classes:

```
class Base 
{
    public Base() { }
}    

class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived() { }   
}
```

The `base`-class´-constructor is automatically invoked when creating the derived one. Therefor it is not possible at all to call the base-class constructor without calling the derived-class one. Only way is create an instance of type `Base` instead of `Derived`, if you create a `Derived` its constructor surely is called.

However if you have a second constrcutor within `Derived` which directly calls the `Base`-one you may of course bypass the defaulöt-constructor of your derived class:

```
class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived() { }   
    public Derived(params object[] args) : base() { }   
}
```

Now you can make the following calls:

```
Derived d = new Derived(); // will call both default-constructors
Derived d1 = new Derived(null); // calls the params-overloaded constructor and not its default one
```

Comment: missing the complete code. made required changes and posted. though correct

Comment: @DDave Complete code? This *is* complete, however not in the meaning of a standalone-console-application, but as an assembly (DLL). However I leave it up to OP to include the code whereever he/she needs it, not neccessarily within a `static void Main`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code::

```
class Base 
{
    public Base() {
        Console.WriteLine("BaseClass Const.");
    }
}    

class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived() { }   
    public Derived(params object[] args) : base() { } 
}

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Derived d = new Derived(null) ;

        }
    }
```

Expected output :

```
BaseClass Const.
```

Comment: Why not modify @HimBromBeere 's answer instead? As it is, his answer is better as it explains why he does everything. You just copied his code and added an implementation example.

Comment: I gave an appropriate answer as expected. Try to post exact answer rather.  I also commented on his post.